# C# How to set and read controls settings from a text document Win Forms

Tags: c#, forms, settings, controls

I need to store few hotkeys and some settings the user can pick in a text document or some alternative to it so that when the user reset's the application the changes wont reset to default. I will need to access some different classes and controls from couple classes. How can i do this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a App.config file.

Your main code:

```
using System.Configuration;

public class WhateverClassName
{
     String setting1 = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Setting1"];
     // all of your code
}
```

Then in the App.config file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <configuration>
      <appSettings>
        <add key="Setting1" value="whatever the setting value is"/>
      </appSettings>
      <startup>
      <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1"/>
      </startup>
    </configuration>
```

Answer (score 4):

If you need to save any kind of information or settings, you could save these settings in a string with certain delimiters in between each property or setting, and write that string into a `.txt` file, as shown here

```
String file = ""; //properties and settings to be saved
string filePath = "C:\\settings.txt"; //path of the settings.txt file
FileStream FS = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Append);
StreamWriter SW = new StreamWriter(FS);
SW.Write(file);
SW.Close();
```

[EDIT]
And when you'd like to read from that file, (which you could do when you load the page) you do the following:

```
string file = ""; //string where you'll read from file
string filePath = "C:\\settings.txt"; //path of the settings.txt file
FileStream FS = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open);
StreamReader SR = new StreamReader(FS);
file = SR.ReadLine;
SR.Close();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This looks like a solution to my problem but just 1 question in what should i put this ? A whole class or in my main form ?

Comment: I'm not sure which is better to be honest, but it will definitely work just as well if you just put it as a function in your code. I'd like anyone who might know which is more correct to give some input on this, but I do know that both will for sure work just as well. And, check the edit I just made on the comment

Answer (score 1):

As *C#/.NET* works with XML, it is better to use **.XML** file for storing your key values.

Or if you don't like the form of XML you can do it with **.ini** file.

A nice tutorial how to use **both** methods is here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5304/Read-Write-XML-files-Config-files-INI-files-or-the

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the built in method for handling settings? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869(v=vs.80).aspx